# How to generate a password protected spreadsheet from PHP?

Tags: php, phpexcel

How to generate a password protected spreadsheet from *PHP* ?

I tried PHPExcel library from http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

PHPExcel offers 3 levels of “protection”: document security, sheet security and cell security.

Document security allows you to set a password on a complete spreadsheet, allowing changes to be made only when that password is entered. But user can open the spreadsheet and view the contents without password.

And I tried Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer as well, but did not find any solution for this. Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer offers only worksheet level security not the file protection.

Does anyone knows any other *PHP* Excel writers which offers file protection where users can't even open the Excel file without the password ?

Comment: Why don't you just protect the download of the file, in other words, if you don't want a user to open it, why would he be able to download it in the first place?

Comment: Is starting with a "passworded" template an option, or do you need the ability to change passwords?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Brad Christie. 
Actually, I would like to create a PHP application, which would be able to generate some excel reports and send that reports to some common path. These reports can be accessible only for some peoples. So I need to protect theses spreadsheets by providing some password security and prevent other users from opening it.

Comment: If PHPExcel and the Pear Excel library don't do it, I highly doubt that you can do it with another lib. Another idea would be to archive (ZIP, RAR...) the spreadsheet with a password with a PHP lib. Use the latest security options as the early ones are really weak.

Answer (score 5):

Full workbook protection entails encryption of the workbook data, and the encryption algorithm used for this is one facet of the Excel format that I have not seen in any of the available documentation. Certainly none of the PHP Excel writer libraries support this: the only way I know to do it (within the workbook itself) is using the COM extension to build your workbook.

Answer (score 2):

You could create the spreadsheet first with PHP and then password protect with the node command-line tool [secure-spreadsheet](https://github.com/ankane/secure-spreadsheet)  It takes either a csv or xlsx and outputs an encrypted xlsx file.

```
$infilepath = 'workbook.xlsx';
$outfilepath = 'workbook-encrypted.xlsx';
$encryptionPassword 'password';

$encryptCommand = "cat $infilepath | /usr/local/bin/secure-spreadsheet --password $encryptionPassword --input-format xlsx > $outfilepath ";

exec($encryptCommand);
```

edit: as per the answer below, the above is now available as a [secure-spreadsheet composer package github](https://github.com/nick322/secure-spreadsheet), it's probably better to use that than exec()
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74372008/2831388

Comment: it is  not working file. Keep showing error message : "No such file or directory"

Comment: you've either not got secure-spreadsheet installed or your $infilepath isn't pointing to an actual file

Answer (score 0):

You could create the spreadsheet first with PHP and then password protect with the [secure-spreadsheet](https://github.com/nick322/secure-spreadsheet) .It take xlsx and outputs an encrypted xlsx file.

```php
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Nick\SecureSpreadsheet\Encrypt;

$test = new Encrypt();
$test->input('Book1.xlsx')
    ->password('111')
    ->output('bb.xlsx');
```