# Can I create Excel file with password protection

Tags: php, excel

Can i create save password protected Excel file with php? I find the a lot of class and method and did't found 
thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a password protected spreadsheet from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471904/how-to-generate-a-password-protected-spreadsheet-from-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use (the excellent) PHPExcel for this. To lock a whole workbook:

```
$reader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007;
$workbook =  $reader->load("document.xlsx");
$workbook->getSecurity()->setWorkbookPassword("your password");
```

Or to lock a sheet:

```
$reader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007;
$workbook =  $reader->load("document.xlsx");
$workbook->-getActiveSheet()->getSecurity()->setWorkbookPassword("your password");
```

Comment: How we write this back to file?

Comment: I tried this and most of the time it didn't do anything at all. When it do something, it locked the file so it could not be edited. It did not do what I expected: require a password to view the file. From what I've seen, PHPExcel cannot truly password protect a file.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No you cannot create a password protected file from PHPExcel until now.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/442#issuecomment-57867961