# How to generate password protected Excel file using PHP?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to create password protected excel file using PHP. Tried many options including PHPExcel library, but its not preventing from Excel from reading. Whenever user tries to open Excel, i need to ask password. I can not go with zipping the file and adding password to it, as suggested in many forums.

Is there any other option ?

Comment: Share some of the problematic code and we can help debug.

Comment: I didn't get any such code yet. I tried PHPExcel library but it prevents only file modification (i.e. user can still read file but can not modify without password).

Comment: My Sample Code :

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Hello');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', 'world!');
$objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setLockWindows(true);
$objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setLockStructure(true);
$objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setWorkbookPassword('1234');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Reports');
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('Reports.xlsx');

Comment: If I remember correctly PhpSpreadsheet only supports protecting data changes, not reading. If you need something like that, you'd probably need to go the password-protected zip route. You can try someone within the PhpSpreadsheet community knows more.

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/3152

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/discussions/3151

Answer (score 1):

PHPExcel does not support writing password-protected files so that they cannot be read without entering the password; the password protection features in PHPExcel are only to prevent editing of data, changing the structure of the worksheets, etc

Comment: I'll take your word for it then.... I wasn't aware that I'd implemented password protection for opening files

Comment: If I remember correctly PhpSpreadsheet only supports protecting data changes, not reading. If you need something like that, you'd probably need to go the password-protected zip route. You can try someone within the PhpSpreadsheet community knows more.

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/3152

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/discussions/3151

Answer (score -2):

There is a duplicate of It I hope?

[Go Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230555/can-i-create-excel-file-with-password-protection)

```
$reader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007;
$workbook =  $reader->load("document.xlsx");
$workbook->-getActiveSheet()->getSecurity()->setWorkbookPassword("your password");
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I already tried this, but it prevents only file modification.

Comment: If I remember correctly PhpSpreadsheet only supports protecting data changes, not reading. If you need something like that, you'd probably need to go the password-protected zip route. You can try someone within the PhpSpreadsheet community knows more.

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/3152

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/discussions/3151

Answer (score -2):

[Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639731/protect-the-excel-file-using-phpexcel)

```
    $objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setLockWindows(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setLockStructure(true);

    $objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setWorkbookPassword('secret');
```

for worksheet security:it is working for me!

```
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSort(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setInsertRows(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setFormatCells(true);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setPassword('password');
```

but for work book security,phpExcel have a issue i think, still exploring

Comment: No dear nothing related to os.Because i am using windows and when trying to do this the worksheet is working fine but the workbook password is not working.your approaching is correct.once try for the worksheet.