# Password protection excel sheet using PHPexcel class

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am trying to create a password protected excel sheet using PHPexcel here is my code :

```
<?php
    require_once '../classes/PHPExcel.php';
    include '../classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel(); 
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Hello'); 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', 'world!');
    $objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setLockWindows(true); 
    $objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setLockStructure(true); 
    $objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setWorkbookPassword('1234'); 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Reports'); 
    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel); 
    $objWriter->save('Reports.xlsx');

?>
```

But when I open `Reports.xlsx` file it does not ask for any password. What is wrong in this code ? I tried this code [Can I create Excel file with password protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230555/can-i-create-excel-file-with-password-protection) from stackoverflow

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just saw this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/7230641/3012938](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7230641/3012938) it'll help. It has an answer to your question.

Comment: @PatrickMutwiri I have already used that code but it is not asking for any password.

Comment: any errors? debug trace?

Comment: PHPExcel doesn't provide encryption of the workbook. The password only prevents modification, there's nothing on preventing people from opening and viewing the .xls. Your best option is to wrap the file in a password protected zip.

Comment: I think there's an issue with workbook security. Use worksheet one.

Comment: This can work `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setPassword('password');`

Comment: @PatrickMutwiri same result not asking for password :(

Comment: @DaveChen is there any way can we protect the excel sheet using password ?

Comment: There is no functionality built in to create a file that requires a password to open. This is not an __issue__ simply a feature of Excel that has never been implemented in PHPExcel

Answer (score 1):

After googling and commenting, I saw this url https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/442 
That feature doesn't work. You can only prevent the cells from being written into.